# Positive Pearson but negative Spearman and Kendall

Tags: r, regression, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I tried all 3 correlation tests, and got the following results:
Pearson's test: 0.04132983
Spearman's test: -0.009821993
Kendall's test: -0.02230622

I don't understand how the values can be so vastly different. Especially since I read Pearson and Spearman produce similar results. I am comparing 2 values, one ordinal (year) and one continuous (price). They are both normal, but price is not linear, so they don't produce a linear plot. Which result should I trust?

EDIT: This is the x,y scatterplot, x is price, y is year.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the plot?

Comment: (1) recall that all three correlations lie in $[-1,1]$, and your values are all very close to zero. I would not call these "vastly different". How large is your sample size? Are your correlations each even significantly different from zero? (2) What do you mean by "price is not linear"? Do you mean that the *relationship* between the two is not linear? (3) Whether your observations are normal is irrelevant. (4) I second Firebug's request for a scatterplot.

Comment: The relationship is not monotonic, correlation coefficients shouldn't be good descriptors of it

Comment: @Stephen Kolassa 1)My sample size is 17. All the correlations have an approximate p-value of 0.9, so they are not significant. 2)No, I made seperate scatterplots for the two variables too, and while year is a perfect line, price is not. 4)I edited my original post.

Comment: @Firebug what do you suggest I should use? I have to answer if time affects the price.

Comment: @Firebug is spot-on, Anna. A nonparametric smoothing regression might be useful (although the sample size is tiny, so maybe not?).

Comment: @Alexis thank you! Would you consider year a categorical variable or a numerical one? It has 17 consecutive year values.

Comment: @Anna It depends on what you are theorizing. *time* is continuous (at least down the the Planck scale), but sometimes we theorize time in meaningfully discrete units (e.g., academic years, pregnancies, etc.). In either case, your variable **year** is  *ordered*, not unordered categories.